# Replacing NAs with 0 for raster data using R

Tags: raster, r, missing-data, replace

I am new in R.

How can I replace NAs with 0 for my raster data which have spatial information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace NA's with 0 for large raster data using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278319/replace-nas-with-0-for-large-raster-data-using-r). I suggesting it to become a dupe from newer version (which addresses other/better options for large datasets). Moreover, OP there linked in Q my answer here; so that question's starting point is this Q/A answer anyway. I think it improves searchability.

Answer (score 29):

The answer from Wilfried Thuiller in [R-SIG-Geo](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/NA-raster-replace-td6348031.html) mailing list works:

```
#getting a raster
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
r <- raster(f) #r is the object of class 'raster'.

# replacing NA's by zero
r[is.na(r[])] <- 0
```