# Replace NA's with 0 for large raster data using R?

Tags: raster, r, missing-data, replace, memoryerror

I want to replace all NA values in a large raster with 0. I found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66792/16141) to [Replacing NAs with 0 for raster data using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66789) :

```
#getting a raster
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
r <- raster(f) #r is the object of class 'raster'.

# replacing NA's by zero
r[is.na(r[])] <- 0
```

but it's not working for my case because the raster is too large thus the computer runs out of memory. Is there an other solution which is more memory efficient?

Answer (score 10):

`"external/test.grd"` isn't the best way to test this. Is a very small raster, so results can't be applied in a large raster.

Here I present a comparison with 4 different approaches, the file used is a mosaic of 12 tiles of ALOS DEM 30m (size per tile: 1x1 degree). Options `a` and `b` are the most suitable for small rasters, let's see if they are good for big ones:

```r
library(raster)
library(microbenchmark)

r <- raster('~/path/to/mosaic.tif')

NAvalue(r) <- -9999

r <- setMinMax(r)

plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
plot(is.na(r))
```

[image]

```r
microbenchmark(a = r[is.na(r[])] <- 0,
               b = values(r)[is.na(values(r))] <- 0,
               c = raster::mask(r,is.na(r),maskvalue = 1, updatevalue = 0),
               d = reclassify(r, cbind(NA, NA, 0), right=FALSE),
               times = 100L)

## Unit: seconds
##  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##     a 1.653149 1.898718 2.031415 1.971430 2.120584 3.352690   100 ab 
##     b 1.707620 1.938079 2.126679 2.089398 2.235046 3.033048   100  b 
##     c 4.362750 5.176214 5.413074 5.471538 5.660152 6.599903   100   c
##     d 1.424628 1.791048 1.935061 1.860629 2.044008 2.753409   100 a
```

Option `d` seems to be a slightly efficient, but there isn't significant differences in this case. Maybe in bigger rasters could be.

Comment: I run into `cannot allocate allocate vector of size #Gb` with methods a and b. And it takes 4 minutes with `reclassify` using `cbind(NA, NA, 0)` vs. `reclassify` using `cbind(NA, 0)` that takes 2.3 minutes (I only ran it once). My raster has 7*1E8 cells.

Comment: @user3386170 is an error derived of memory used for this process considering a big raster, use `gc()` before to apply those functions

Comment: BTW, method d seems to be the fastest, so a and b are other good options... c is not the best way to replace NA's

Comment: Even with `gc()`, I still cannot run the a and b methods. My dataset suggests that there is a significant difference between the methods (method d works). Just adding a tidbit of information for other users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `terra::subst`

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
```

Solution

```
x <- subst(r, NA, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `raster::calc()` as perhaps a more memory efficient method. So, guessing that you have a single-layer raster you can do the following to replace `NA` values (used some test data here):

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=1E3, ncol=1E3)
values(r) <- NA


replaceNA <- function(x, na.rm, ...){ 
  if(is.na(x[1]))
    return(0)
  else
    return(x)
} 

r <- calc(r, fun = replaceNA)
```

I was able to run this replacement in a test raster layer with 1E8 `NA` pixels without running out of memory.

Comment: This version took 20.83649 mins instead of 2-4 minutes with `reclassify` with my dataset of 7*10E8.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question - but still very relevant. I  found classify using terra was very time and memory efficient. I was going from zero to NA.

```
r <- raster(nrow=1E3, ncol=1E3)
values(r) <- NA

reclass_mat <- matrix(c(0, NA), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

test <- classify(r_in), reclass_mat, right = F)
```

Comment: Actually,  if needing to stay memory safe in terra you could use `x <- terra::ifel(x == NA, 0, x)` and if it can be processed in-memory, a bracket index `x[is.na(x)] <- 0` Since this is a conditional evaluation of only a single value, and not all values like in `terra::classify`, it is much faster and efficient.