# Getting a masked raster with no NAs and sum pixels within overlaying polygon?

Tags: raster, r, polygon, zonal-statistics, missing-data

I have done an IDW interpolation in R for precipitation data following the routine of Manny Gimond (https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html) to get precipitation inside a catchment.

Here is the routine:

```
library(gstat) #Use gstat's idw routine
library(sp)    #Used for the spsample function

#Create an empty grid where n is the total number of cells
grd <- as.data.frame(spsample(P, "regular", n=50000))
names(grd) <- c("X", "Y")
coordinates(grd) <- c("X", "Y")
gridded(grd) <- TRUE  # Create SpatialPixel object
fullgrid(grd) <- TRUE  # Create SpatialGrid object

# Add P's projection information to the empty grid
proj4string(grd) <- proj4string(P)

# Interpolate the grid cells using a power value of 2 (idp=2.0)
P.idw <- gstat::idw(Precip_in ~ 1, P, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)

# Convert to raster object then clip to Texas
r <- raster(P.idw)
r.m <- mask(r, W)
```

The problem is that in the last step (i.e masking the raster with interpolated values (r) to the boundaries of the geometry of interest) a great number of NA values appear that correspond to point lying out of the masking polygon.

What I am looking for is a function to use in conjunction with `mask` that ensures that in the final masked raster these NA values are removed so that I have raster with no NA value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish, i.e., summing pixel values from a raster based on an overlaying vector polygon is called in GIS: **Zonal Statistics**.

In R, one can use the `extract` function for this. For example:

```
extract(r, W, fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

About excluding NA pixels from the raster object, it is what [Spacedman's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300329/r-raster-how-to-get-a-masked-raster-with-no-na-values-after-masking/300350#300350) said (also in [Remove NA from Raster Layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219992/remove-na-from-raster-layer)) one can't actually remove such pixels to get an 'irreguar shaped raster', only replacing its values. So, replacing NA values for zero in a masked raster would also work if one just wanted to sum all values in it. See [Replace NA's with 0 for raster data using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66789/replace-nas-with-0-for-raster-data-using-r/66792#66792).

Answer (score 2):

> What I am looking for is a function to use in conjunction with `mask` that ensures that in the final masked raster these NA values are removed so that I have raster with no NA value.

A raster is an NxM grid where every cell has a value. If the value is not known, it is generally set to NA (or some special value like "-9999"). There's no way you can "remove" a value from a cell without replacing it with something else.